# How can I remove the disabled attribute from my select box with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple select box:

```
   <select class="select">
                <option data-number="0" disabled>0</option>     
                <option data-number="1" disabled>1</option> 
                <option data-number="1" disabled>2</option>     
    </select>
```

If the data-number is 0, the attribute `disabled` should be removed. The way I did it is not working:

```
$(#'input').change(function () {
    if ($('.select').data('number') == 0) {
                alert("Hello! This working!!");
                $(this).data('number').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

I do not get the alert, when I select `0` (Note: Of course I cannot select a disabled option manually, but the system selects it automatically on an input change)

Comment: How can you select any value if all options are disabled by default?

Comment: It is automatically selected on an input change

Comment: The problem is `$(this).data('number')` - that returns the value of the "data-number" attribute. I don't know what you expect that to do, but it's not going to let you change the "disabled" attribute of the `<option>` element.

Comment: OK, can you post the code that does the selection? Also why do you use "data-number" ant not "value" ?

Comment: Well I think I found my mistake. It is somewhere else in my code... I set the disabled attribute with this code: `$(this).prop('disabled', ($(this).data('number') < that ))` but what I need is something like `$(this).prop('disabled', ($(this).data('number') < that && =! 0 ))` So the `disabled` attribute will not be added to the 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace:

```
if ($('.select').data('number') == 0) {
    alert("Hello! This working!!");
    $(this).data('number').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

With:

```
$('select.select option[data-number=0]').prop('disabled', false);
```

```js
$('select.select option[data-number=0]').prop('disabled', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select class="select">
  <option data-number="0" disabled>0</option>
  <option data-number="1" disabled>1</option>
  <option data-number="1" disabled>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try utilizing selector `$(".select option")` , `.filter()`

```js
$(".select option").filter(function() {
  return $(this).data().number === 0
}).prop("disabled", false)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select class="select">
  <option data-number="0" disabled>0</option>
  <option data-number="1" disabled>1</option>
  <option data-number="1" disabled>2</option>
</select>
```